# Relationship among different RDMA libraries

Tags: infiniband, rdma

I'm new to RDMA technology, and I'm confused by several rdma libraries. I cannot figure out the relationship among them. The libraries and kernel headers I'm confused with are as follows:

***1.rdma-core/libibverbs***

***2.rdma-core/librdmacm***

***3.linux-5.4.2/include/rdma***

***4.linux-5.4.2/iniclude/uapi/rdma***

My question is:

1.As far as I know. ***libibverbs*** provides the userspace applications with verbs api(i.e. functions with prefix ***ibv_***), but it does not offer any connection-related functions, so applications need to exchange connection information using sockets(I see this operation in the libibverbs example ***rc_pingpong.c***). ***librdmacm*** provides the user with easier connection management mechanism(e.g. ***rdma_get_cm_event***). However, it seems that ***librdmacm*** does more work than connection management, since it also defines several apis(e.g. ***rdma_create_qp*** in ***rdma_cma.h***) which looks similar to the ***ibv_function*** in ***libibverbs***. So I do not know whether ***librdmacm*** is a superset of ***libibverbs***? If not, what's the relationship between them?

2.In the example ***rc_pingpong.c*** of ***libibverbs***, I cound see it includes the header file ***verbs.h***, and it seems that ***linux-5.4.2/include/rdma*** and ***linux-5.4.2/iniclude/uapi*** do not play any role in the program(no heaer files in these two directories are included). So what are the header files in these two directories aimed at?

I have refer to several materials but have not made it clear. Any explanation or related resources are well-appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Anything in linux but not in uapi is for the kernel only